# call a function recusively and store it into an int gives me 1?

Tags: c++, recursion

This code runs fine and is used to find the Largest Factor between two numbers, but I wanted to know why num prints out what it does (for this example 1 1 1 3 at the end of the program). I am confused why we can store a function into an int and then we get back a number? Why does it give us a 1?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int LargestFactor(int number, int start)
{
  if(start == number)
   return 1;
  int num = LargestFactor(number, start+1);
  cout << num;
  if (num ==1 && number % start == 0)
   return start;

 return num; 

}

int main()
{
  LargestFactor(6,2);

}
```

Comment: Make sure that each of the three `return` statements in `LargestFactor` are returning what you want them to return.

Comment: Did you try to debug? Because you call `LargestFactor` recursively and then print the value returned. So it starts printing with the end.

Comment: It gives you a 1 because it reaches the `return 1` line on some of the calls.